# How to choose technology to create mobile app with 3D object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, 3d, nativescript, cross-platform

I am a Vue JS developer(frontend)

I have a task to create mobile app for Android and IOS.
I didn't develop any mobile apps before

I have to choose a technology for creating this app.

There is 3D object on main screen. User can rotate object with fingers. There are buttons also around this 3D object. So a user can rotate the 3D object, click on any button on that object and current screen go to another screen.

I recently discovered Nativescript framework that can help to develop mobile apps for Android and IOS with any frontend framework like Vue or Angular, but I don't know if it can support any javascript libraries like THREE JS, to interract with 3D objects.

I also know there is Unity platform that can create games for different platforms, but I don'r know if there is a possibility to create an application not a a game.

3D object was made in Unity and has extension .obj

**What technologies should I pick to create an application like this?**

[Example](https://mega.nz/file/qJl33KrI#3Fi2N83-_y8zAbSFL0RJ9A_vEeFRhcB8W3g-PzdFi-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe looks like interface of a game pretty much.
Also Unity is not just for games, its is used for simulators, training of surgeons etc.
It is very flexible tool.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm not familair with C#, I only know Javascript,is it possible to make an application in unity in Javascript or without any language at all?

Comment: It is possible with javascript, but most tutorials i see are in c#. I dont know how easy it is to find guides in javascript.